# Is it possible to call $div1.toggle() in $div2.click()?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to call $div1.toggle() in $div2.click() so that the stage can be changed based on div1.toggle 's stage after clicking div2?

```
price =0;
var $seatdiv = $('<div id = "seat'+i+'" class="seat"></div>')
.toggle(function(){ 
price =price+15.50; 
   ,function(){
price = price-15.50;});


var $dltDiv = $('<div id="dlt_seat'+i+'" 
class="ticket-item"><a href="#">delete</a></div>').click(function(){
price = price-15.50; });
```

The situation is: 1.click seatDiv (price change to 15.50); 2. click dltDiv (price change to 0); 3. click seatDiv again (price change to -15.50 where is wrong).

Who can help? Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Comment: yes ofcourse it is possible only.

Comment: Why are you using [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)? Can you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

jQuery:

```
var price = 0;
$('div.ticket-item').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("dlt_", "");
    var a = $(this).children("a");
    $(a).toggle(function(){
        $(a).text('delete');
        price = price + 15.50;
        $('#total').empty().append(price);
    }, function() {
        $(a).text('add');
        price = price - 15.50;
        $('#total').empty().append(price);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/ESqFK/

you can append that price on your div1 instead of divtotal.. i just wanted to demonstrate how does this work.